# movie clip on click at mouse coordinates prevent mouse click

Tags: actionscript-3, click, mouse

I want to add at each click a movie clip (it's smoke, as the pointer is a gun).

I've managed to do that, BUT now I can't clik on anything (buttons,objects..etc). The smoke appears juste fine but seems to "block" the click.

Do you know how I can resolve this issue ?

Here's my code :

```
private var fumee:MovieClip;

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, tire, false, 0, true); 

public function tire(e:MouseEvent):void{
        fumee = new fumeeFusil;
        addChild(fumee);
            fumee.x = mouseX;
            fumee.y = mouseY;

        }
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure your `fummeFusil` instances are not mouse-accessible:

```
public function tire(e:MouseEvent):void{
    fumee = new fumeeFusil;

    // setting both mouseEnabled and mouseChildren to false will ensure
    // that you cannot click on the MovieClip
    fumee.mouseEnabled = fumee.mouseChildren = false;

    addChild(fumee);
        fumee.x = mouseX;
        fumee.y = mouseY;

}
```